# Schrödinger equation for the 'octal' spherical harmonic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Would it be possible to develop an analogy for the Schrödinger equation for an octal spherical harmonics?

Some background

> The cubical atom was an early atomic model in which electrons were positioned at the eight corners of a cube in a non-polar atom or molecule. This theory was developed in 1902 by Gilbert N. Lewis and published in 1916... It was further developed in 1919 by Irving Langmuir as the cubical octet atom. [image]
>   Although the cubical model of the atom was soon abandoned in favor of the quantum mechanical model based on the Schrödinger equation, and is therefore now principally of historical interest... ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubical_atom))

Here are the relevant spherical harmonics:

> [image]
>     [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics)

Right top is the spherical harmonics for the p-shell (the s- shell has to be calculated separately), left bottom is the octal spherical harmonics.

Comment: Note that nothing in your second diagram depicts p-shell electrons. Those are the four $l=3$ spherical harmonics and as such they are the shapes of the f-shell orbitals.

Comment: The question as written doesn't make any sense. There is nothing about the Schrödinger equation that makes it 'for' particular spherical harmonics. For spherically symmetric potentials the eigensolution include *all* the spherical harmonics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

What you call the "octal" spherical harmonic (by no means a standard term), i.e. $Y_{3,2}(\theta, \phi)$, is a single function, and it therefore represents a single orbital, which fits a single electron. Cutting it up into octants is pretty much equivalent to cutting up $\sin(x)$ into the intervals $(n\pi,(n+1)\pi)$, drawing doors and windows on them, and pretending that they're little houses where electrons can live.

Now, you can go on and formulate whatever interpretation you want of bits of QM that you've cut-and-pasted to try and fit the mold of other failed scientific theories, but if you intentionally set out to break quantum mechanics, you'll mostly just get nonsense. In this specific case that's all that's come out.